# GTK Retrieve values from multiple widgets on button press

Tags: c, parsing, button, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to retrieve a value from both an Entry field and a ComboBox in my window on a button press. I'm currently struggling to do so. I've been told that in order to get multiple value, I need to use structs. However I'm struggling to get it to work. Here is what I have so far:

Function to be run on button press:

```
struct data {
    GtkWidget *hash;
    GtkWidget *hashType;
};

static void queue_hash (struct data *dataStruct) {

    GtkWidget *hashWid = dataStruct->hash;
    GtkWidget *hashTypeWid = dataStruct->hashType;

    const char* hash = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(hashWid));
    char* hashType = gtk_combo_box_text_get_active_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(hashTypeWid));

    g_print ("Queue Hash: %s    %s\n", hash, hashType);

}
```

Button:

```
GtkWidget *hashEntry;
GtkWidget *hashSelect;

hashEntry = gtk_entry_new(); 
gtk_widget_set_size_request(hashEntry, 290, 33);
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(window_fixed), hashEntry, 300, 75);

hashSelect = gtk_combo_box_text_new();
gtk_widget_set_size_request(hashSelect, 102, 25);
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(window_fixed), hashSelect, 595, 75); 

gtk_combo_box_text_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(hashSelect), "MD5");
gtk_combo_box_text_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(hashSelect), "SHA1"); 


queueButtonBox = gtk_button_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
queueButton = gtk_button_new_with_label("Queue Hash");

gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(window_fixed), queueButtonBox, 300, 120);


struct data *cb_data = g_new0(struct data, 1);
cb_data->hash = hashEntry;
cb_data->hashType = hashSelect;
g_signal_connect (queueButton, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (queue_hash), cb_data);
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
(SDS-CW:16982): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 14:42:38.659: invalid uninstantiatable type 'void' in cast to 'GtkEntry'

(SDS-CW:16982): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:42:38.659: gtk_entry_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_ENTRY (entry)' failed
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How are `hashentry` and `hashSelect` defined and initialized?

Comment: @Gerhardh Please accept my apologies for the lack of responsiveness, I am usually very responsive, however have had several things come up unexpectedly over the past couple of days that I've had to deal with that have drawn my attention away. HashEntry and HashSelect are defined as follows:

Comment: @Gerhardh `GtkWidget *hashEntry;
GtkWidget *hashSelect;

hashEntry = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(hashEntry, 290, 33);
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(window_fixed), hashEntry, 300, 75);

    hashSelect = gtk_combo_box_text_new();
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(hashSelect, 102, 25);
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(window_fixed), hashSelect, 595, 75);
    gtk_combo_box_text_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(hashSelect), "MD5");
    gtk_combo_box_text_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(hashSelect), "SHA1");
`

Comment: No need to appologize. As soon as you provide the missing information, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html#GtkButton-clicked) tells us that the signal handler for `"clicked"` signal must follow this signature:

```
void
user_function (GtkButton *button,
               gpointer   user_data)
```

You function only expects 1 parameter and is invalid for this signal. As a result you take the `button` pointer and interpret it as your struct which will fail.

To solve this problem either provide a signature taking both parameters or you could connect the signal hander with function `g_signal_connect_swapped`.

You could change your initial handler function like this:

```
static void queue_hash (GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data) {

    struct data *dataStruct = user_data;

    GtkWidget *hashWid = dataStruct->hash;
    GtkWidget *hashTypeWid = dataStruct->hashType;

    const char* hash = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(hashWid));
    char* hashType = gtk_combo_box_text_get_active_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(hashTypeWid));

    g_print ("Queue Hash: %s    %s\n", hash, hashType);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I obviously misread that it was required syntax, so my apologies. I have now updated my code to reflect that change, however I'm struggling to see how I then utilise those parameters to obtain the values of the two widgets I'm trying to access? Sorry, I'm very new to GTK, and I'm struggling to get my head around it. Thanks

Comment: You were accessing the values in the correct way but from an invalid parameter. Try the same with updated function signature.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help up to this point, I really appreciate it! Once again sorry for thaking a few days to respond, this has really been on the backburner with a lot I have had come up. I have implemented your changes, however am still seeing this error: `(SDS-CW:25413): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 19:18:19.125: gtk_entry_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_ENTRY (entry)' failed` and I'm struggling to see why?

Comment: Please post a new question and provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your changes.Without seeing all relevant code this cannot be answered.

Comment: If you feel that an answer helped solving a problem you might think about upvoting and/or accepting it.

Comment: I have asked a new question containing my full code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60747138/gtk-retrieve-multiple-values-from-widgets-on-button-press